# How to prevent two objects from having the same two identical attributes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Quick background: I am creating a simple app where user can add another user as friend. A lot taken from this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association?autoplay=true). To do it, I created a `Friendship` model to keep track of which `User` I have added.

Here is what I have:

```
#Friendship.all
[#<Friendship id: 3, user_id: 6, friend_id: 5, created_at: "2017-09-19 ...
#<Friendship id: 13, user_id: 1, friend_id: 2, created_at: "2017-09-22 17:33:47", updated_at: "2017-09-22 17:33:47">, 
#<Friendship id: 14, user_id: 1, friend_id: 2, created_at: "2017-09-22 18:47:52", updated_at: "2017-09-22 18:47:52">]>
```

Note that I am (`user1`) currently able to add the same user twice. If you look at the result of `Friendship.all`, the last two have `user_id: 1, friend_id: 2` twice.

In short, I need to make sure my `Friendship` model don't have two of matching attributes like the above. Being `user1`, I should not be allowed to add `user2` twice. I don't think Rails' [`uniqueness`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) validation works in this situation.

Is there a Rails' way of preventing duplicates of creating an object with two of the same attributes like shown above?

Comment: There was another similar post. My solution: `validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :friend_id`